# Sci Fi story that was made on wordpress online, like 2019

Tags: story-identification

I only read the first chapter. Starts with a US navy destroyer fighting 3 Mainland Chinese ships with help of a US submarine ship. They were fighting to protect a Taiwanese ship. Its has something to do with aliens though, eventually. It was completed by the time I had got around time I got around to read it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a serial, like a chapter-a-week book, or was it complete, and you just didn't read all of it?  Do you recall _why_ the US and Chinese were fighting?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.